# How does spring do dependency injection when there are multiple injection components candidates to inject

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I am trying to understand how spring dependency injection works. Based on my understanding, if we declare a class as a bean with `@Component` annotation and use the `@Autowired` annotation for that bean in another class where the dependency needs to be injected, it will inject that bean as a dependency. For e.g.

Let's say we have `IService` interface and `Service1` implements `Iservice`, and we declare `Service1` as a  `component`. If we have a main class with `Iservice` reference, and we do `autowired` annotation on Iservice reference, `Service1` will be injected into `Iservice` reference.

However, my question is that if there are two classes `Service1` and `Service2` that implement `Iservice`,and we use `autowiring`. How will spring decide which Service class to use for dependency injection?

Comment: Use `@Qualifier`

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than 1 class for autowire candidate, you should use `@Qualifier` along with `@Autowired`

Comment: Yep, that's what I came to write :)